# C++ Boost::ASIO Thread Pool issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, threadpool

I just created my Thread Pool for game server, but i got one error in compiling what i didn't know how to fix.

Error :

> Connection/CConnection.cpp: In lambda function:
>   Connection/CConnection.cpp:62:6: error: 'this' was not captured for
>   this lambda function

Thread Pool declaration :

```
class Worker {
public:
    Worker(ThreadPool &s) : pool(s) { }
    void operator()();
private:
    ThreadPool &pool; 
};

// the actual thread pool
class ThreadPool {
public:
    ThreadPool(size_t);
    template<class F>
    void enqueue(F f);
    ~ThreadPool();
private:
    // need to keep track of threads so we can join them
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<boost::thread> > workers;

    // the io_service we are wrapping
    boost::asio::io_service service;
    boost::asio::io_service::work working;
    friend class Worker;
};

template<class F>
void ThreadPool::enqueue(F f)
{
    service.post(f);
}
```

Function what use it :

```
void CConnection::handle()
{
     int i = 0;
     ThreadPool pool(4);
     pool.enqueue([i]
    {
     char * databuffer;
     databuffer = new char[16];
     for(int i = 0;i<16;i++)
     {
      databuffer[i] = 0x00;
     }
     databuffer[0] = 16;
     databuffer[4] = 1;
     databuffer[8] = 1;
     databuffer[12] = 1;
     asynchronousSend(databuffer, 16);
    });
}
```

Can someone tell me where, and what is problem ?

Comment: Are you sure you want the threadpool to be a normal local variable in the `handle` function? Remember it will be destructed when the `handle` function returns.

Comment: Yes i know, i just put it into this to compile tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `asynchronousSend` is a function in the `CConnection` class. To call function in object you have to capture `this`:

```
pool.enqueue([this] { ... });
```

As you see I've removed the capture of `i` as it's not needed, since you declare a local `i` inside the lambda.